# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

When I am trying to fling example this error faced. with java Null pointer exception

i am getting NullPointerException at line this      actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

```
TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Tab = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar = getActionBar();
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        // Enable Tabs on Action Bar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                    FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                    FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };
        // Add New Tab
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Android").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("iOS").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Windows").setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
```

Comment: post the stack trace please

Comment: so `actionBar` is null, check that, what is the minimum sdk version?  if your version is lower that 14 you must use `getSupportActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using a theme with no ActionBar. As you can see on the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getActionBar%28%29) it returns null when your Activity has no ActionBar. Check your AndroidManifest and use a theme with ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

Does your activity have an action bar? As the documentation of [getActionBar()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getActionBar()) says that it returns `The Activity's ActionBar, or null if it does not have one.`

Answer (score 0):

Extend your activity by ActionBarActivity.

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    private android.support.v7.app.ActionBar  actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    }
```

replace your 
actionBar = getActionBar(); 
with 
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
and always use this code to get action bar.
Now it won't give error. Enjoy